# Python- Calculate the sum of product of items in a tuple

Tags: python

Consider following tuple:

```
[(1,3),(2,4)]
```

I want to use sum function to calculate sum of product of items in a tuple, that is:

[image]

Here is my try:

```
tpl=[(1,3),(2,4)]
sum(item[0]*item[1] for item in tpl)
11
```

This  works, but I assumed the length of each item inside "tpl" is 2.

```
tpl=[(1,3,1),(2,4,3)]
sum(item[0]*item[1]*item[2] for item in tpl)
```

How to extend the above method for a custom tuple like

```
tpl=[(a1,...,an),(b1,...,bn)]?
```

Comment: `reduce()` might help.

Comment: Apply answer in duplicate to each element of `tpl`.

Comment: This should work `sum(map(math.prod,tpl))`